# Where is Criterion's output, or how do I enable it?

Tags: rust, rust-criterion

The [Criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) benchmarking library for Rust is documented as [generating plots](https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/user_guide/plots_and_graphs.html) describing the benchmark results:

> Criterion.rs can generate a number of useful charts and graphs which you can check to get a better understanding of the behavior of the benchmark.

> The plots and saved data are stored under `target/criterion/$BENCHMARK_NAME/`.

However, after running `cargo bench` and seeing Criterion's output on the terminal, I don't see a directory named `target/criterion/`. Where is the output now, or what do I have to do to activate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a small bug ([criterion issue #192](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs/issues/192)): when Criterion is used in a *Cargo workspace*, it doesn't find the workspace's `target` directory, and ends up writing its results to `<individual crate directory>/target/criterion` instead.

The Cargo extension [cargo-criterion](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-criterion) was supposed to [work around this](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs/pull/337#issuecomment-660512596) but unfortunately for my particular case, [currently didn't work on macOS (cargo-criterion issue #12)](https://github.com/bheisler/cargo-criterion/issues/12).

Both issues has been fixed; since version 0.3.4 `criterion` writes its output to the correct directory, and `cargo-criterion` also works on macOS.

Comment: Is there anything I have to configure or pass to `cargo bench` to activate HTML reports / plot output? I'm using version 0.4.0 and I'm getting no HTML reports whatsoever using cargo workspace as well. To clarify, `target/criterion` contains some json files, but no html/png/svg files at all.

Comment: I looks like it is now disabled by default and hidden behind a feature flag (`criterion = { version = "0.4", features = ["html_reports"] }`), which apparently now gets [reported frequently as an issue](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs/issues/632), because the documentation and user guide still suggest otherwise.